# How to convert NSData to Array of UInt8 ins iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, byte, uint8t

I have **Swift** code for convert this method:

```
func DATA_TO_UINT8(_ d:Data) -> Array<UInt8> {
        return d.withUnsafeBytes {
            [UInt8](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: (d.count)))
        }
}
```

and now i want it in **Objective C**.

Comment: Why are you using `Array<UInt8>` in the first place? That's the whole point of NSData: to encapsulate a series of bytes.

Comment: I have got response from this code and it's correct. can you tell me convert Data or NSData to array of uint8 in objective c? @Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To produce a stack based array try something like (code typed directly into answer, expect errors):

```
NSData *data = ...

UInt8 buf[data.length]; // local stack array
[data getBytes:buf length:data.length];
```

If you want a heap array you will need to use `malloc` to allocate the memory, if you don't actually need the array just a C pointer you can use the `NSData` `bytes` method.