# Converting Hex String to UInt8 Array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

The String to bytes[]

> NSString *strData = @"ca 20 fe c1 04 03 03 07 00 ac";

The Result is

> UInt8 bytes[]= {0xca,0x20,0xfe,0xc1,0x04,0x03,0x03,0x07,0x01,0xac};

for swift code, how convert to Objective-C

> ```
>     let data = NSString(string : "ca 20 fe c1 04 03 03 07 01 ac");
>     let dataArr = data.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
>     var bytes : [UInt8] = [];
>
>     for item in dataArr {
>         let byte = UInt8(item, radix: 16)
>         bytes.append(byte!);
>     }
>
>     let hexData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: 10)
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317860/converting-hex-nsstring-to-nsdata + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907919/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-array-of-uint8-ins-ios-objective-c ?

Comment: @Larme thanks, but can't work, the data no correct，ca convert to 202，but -54 is correct

Comment: "ca convert to 202，but -54 is correct" what? What -54? What code did you tried exactly?

Comment: @Larme The Java Code screenshot http://uploads.im/tj7Fi.png

Comment: `UInt8` How are you supposed to get -54 with `UInt8`, which `U` stands for unsigned. That's where lies your issue. Also, in the Swift Code, there should also have the issue.

Comment: @Larme I want use socket send hex data to server，the swift\java code send success, but objective-c can't